# On a Spanish work visa can I initially enter the EU via another country? Do I have to do something when I arrive in Spain to let them know I'm there?

Tags: spain, eu

I'm from the US and will be traveling to Spain to work. My family and I will have Spanish work visas, but we are planning to fly to Amsterdam for a few days before flying to Spain.

Since there are no border controls between the Netherlands and Spain, it seems that Spain would never see our visas. Is that ok? Do we have to go to Spain first? Or do we need to report our arrival to the authorities when we arrive? (I know there are some additional steps after arrival regardless of how we get there, like getting a social security number, but I'm wondering about anything *in addition* due to entering Europe via another country).

Answer (score 3):

In general, Spain wants you to register your residence within thirty days of arrival.  Go to the nearest *ayuntamiento* and ask about *empadronamiento* and how to do it.  If it doesn’t apply to a work visa (which I doubt), they can tell you.

Each local government’s share of national funds is proportional to how many people have *padrón* in that jurisdiction.

https://www.expatica.com/es/living/gov-law-admin/el-padron-849450/

Comment: Adding to this answer, yes you can enter through another country with the Spanish visa D. The Netherlands will have access to the visa information from Spain when you present the document. Enjoy!

Comment: Also to add to this answer, the same requirement exists for someone who enters Spain directly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the first thing you do is to obtain NIE:

https://www.exteriores.gob.es/Embajadas/telaviv/en/ServiciosConsulares/Paginas/Consular/NIE.aspx

In general, when opening a bank account, obtaining empadronamiento or medical security card it is the first thing they ask for.